# How to see the changes happened in a file, resulted by uncommitted changes git?

Tags: git, git-diff

Suppose I am in someBranch in git and I have made some changes to files `file1` and `file2` which are not committed yet.

Is there a way/git command to see(cat in linux) the lines I have changed of a given file(ex: `file1`) in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just modified the file but not `git add` yet, `git diff` or `git diff -- file1`.

If you have added it but not committed, `git diff --cached` or `git diff --cached -- file1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff file1
```

[git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please give the exact command matches with the scenario I have given. I know git-diff only to compare 2 branches.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne git diff file1

Comment: could you please add that to your answer too?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need look [at](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command

```
git diff [file]
```

It will show uncommitted changes to specific file

Here is how you can do it:

```
git diff path/file1
```

And live example :

```
git diff common/models/Transaction.php


diff --git a/common/models/Transaction.php b/common/models/Transaction.php
index d45cccd..5e3ffd4 100644
--- a/common/models/Transaction.php
+++ b/common/models/Transaction.php
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@ use Yii;
 class Transaction extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
 {

-    const TYPE_PURCHASE  = 'PURCHASE';
+    const TYPE_PURCHASE  = 'purchase';

     const STATUS_NORMAL = 'NORMAL';
     const STATUS_NEW = 'NEW';
```